# How to setup up a secure certificate for community

Tags: community, certificates, custom-domain

I've been following [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212707&language=en_US) from Salesforce on how to setup a custom domain for serving up a Salesforce community. On step 2 it says I have to setup a certificate for use with the domain.

My goal is to have a community like:

> https://support.mydomain.com

We already have a wildcard certificate for our domain, but the the instructions in the article make it appear like I cannot use my existing one and I have to create a new one instead.

Do I have to buy a new certificate just for Salesforce or is there some way of using my existing wildcard certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, Salesforce does not allow you to import an existing, signed certificate. You have to go through the process of generating a new Certificate Signing Request, uploading that to your SSL provider, then uploading a new signed certificate.

In my case, that meant buying a new certificate, even though I have an existing wildcard certificate.

Comment: Yes, it is a pain having to get a new CSR and getting the new signed one from the provider, but it needs the information that SF embed in the signing request.

Comment: I was able to import a certificate without doing a CSR; please see my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do it:
Custom Domains: Using an Existing HTTPS Certificate With Your Community
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232390&type=1

It is possible to request a new HTTPS certificate or to reuse certain existing certificates in your community domain. Broadly, there are two options:

1. New certificate:
   If your community will need a new HTTPS certificate, you can follow the instructions in Help & Training to configure & download a new Certificate Signing Request to give to your certificate authority.
2. Using existing certificate for my community domain:
   If your company already has a certificate that matches the domain your community will run under, you can take the steps detailed in the link to import that certificate into a Java keystore (JKS) file to prepare it for upload to your org.

Comment: When posting a link please also include a short synopsis of what is on the link as links often break. See [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import a wildcard certificate to Salesforce from GoDaddy that is used across multiple sites and ORGs.  They 'trick' is to create a JKS file from the private key and certificate and upload that.  That JKS can be reused in multiple ORGs.  On a Mac I took the following steps:

1. Move your private key file and crt file to the same directory
2. Open a terminal window in that directory
3. Run
   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycertificate.crt -inkey generated-private-key.txt -certfile mycertificate.crt -name "Wildcard Certificate" -out mykeystore.p12` (generated-private-key.txt is your key file and mycertificate.crt is the signed certificate)
4. Run
   `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mykeystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS`

The resulting 'keystore.jks' file can then be imported to the Certificates area of Setup in Salesforce.

I did run into one "gotcha": the private key GoDaddy supplied was in a "UTF-8 with BOM" format.  I was able open the file in Visual Studio Code and save it as a UTF-8 file.